# C# DataGridView conditional formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview, conditional-formatting

I am designing an application to manage some assets within my company, and I am trying to essentially toggle the color of the row in my dataGridView on a button click, however, when I try to change the color back to the color that loads on startup, nothing happens and the event is not triggered

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_user != null)// Check for active logged-on user
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;// Cast sender to DataGridView object type

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)// check column is checkbox column
        {
            btnGroupAssets.Enabled = true;// Enable group assets button

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.AliceBlue)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.LightCoral)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login required");// Prompt user for login
        List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();

        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)// Check open forms for login form
            if (f.Name == "Login" || f.Name == "li")// If there is an instance of login, close it
                forms.Add(f);

        foreach (Form f in forms)
            f.Close();

        Login li = new Login();// Open new login form
        li.Show();
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "the event is not triggered" May we have a look on the event bind and the function definition? You must be using the `SelectedIndexChanged`, `void dataGridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Of course. Edited for more clarity

Comment: After moving onto another section of my code, the above has just mysteriously started to work. No changes were made to the code so this may be an issue with my local machine. Thanks for your help anyway, Drag and Drop

Comment: I did Nothing. But it's cool that it works now. For mysterious bug like this I recommend making an [MCVE]. You will be surprice the number of time the solution appear trying to reproducce the issue. Making a simple test with only a 4 row grid with fixed input and working with it.

Comment: Good tip, I'll be sure to do more of that in future! :)

Comment: Btw for your code I will recomment moving `_user != null` else part into a function as you wrote it it seems like every event will have it. So factoring it out should be a good solution. `if(NotLoged()) return;`

Comment: For this case, checking the private field fits with the control flow of my program as this will be checked in the first action the end-users will take. But a good suggestion nonetheless